# Multiple buttons that each segue to multiple ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have one view controller that displays a label with a foreign word.  It has 4 buttons, each with 3 random words and 1 word matching the foreign word.  Upon clicking either of the buttons, it needs to transition into 1 of the 2 view controllers on the bottom.  the one of the left reviews the word if the button you click doesn't match the label and the view controller on the right displays that you got it correct and shows the word in a randomly chosen sentence.

The problem is that I have been googling how to correctly segue multiple views from a single button while passing data at the time for about 5 hours and I cannot come up with a solution.

:EDIT I don't have enough reputation to post images. Sorry! This hurts a lot

I have tried making a complex prepareForSegue() function, but I don't have a way to call it when each of the 4 buttons are pressed.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if ButtonAnswer1.description == testedWord {
        if (segue.identifier == "segueToAnsweredCorrect") {
            var acvc : AnsweredCorrectViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AnsweredCorrectViewController;
                println(testedWord)
                println(randomSentenceToTransfer)
                acvc.testedWord = testedWord
                acvc.sentenceTransferred = randomSentenceToTransfer
            }
        if ButtonAnswer2.description == testedWord {
            if (segue.identifier == "segueToAnsweredCorrect") {
                var acvc : AnsweredCorrectViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AnsweredCorrectViewController;
                println(testedWord)
                println(randomSentenceToTransfer)
                acvc.testedWord = testedWord
                acvc.sentenceTransferred = randomSentenceToTransfer
            }

            if ButtonAnswer3.description == testedWord {
                if (segue.identifier == "segueToAnsweredCorrect") {
                    var acvc : AnsweredCorrectViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AnsweredCorrectViewController;
                    println(testedWord)
                    println(randomSentenceToTransfer)
                    acvc.testedWord = testedWord
                    acvc.sentenceTransferred = randomSentenceToTransfer
                }

                if ButtonAnswer4.description == testedWord {
                    if (segue.identifier == "segueToAnsweredCorrect") {
                        var acvc : AnsweredCorrectViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AnsweredCorrectViewController;
                        println(testedWord)
                        println(randomSentenceToTransfer)
                        acvc.testedWord = testedWord
                        acvc.sentenceTransferred = randomSentenceToTransfer
                    }
            else {
                        func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
                if (segue.identifier == "segueToReviewCard") {
                    var rcvc : ReviewCardViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ReviewCardViewController;
                    rcvc.translationReviewed = testedTranslation
                    rcvc.wordReviewed = testedWord
                }
            }
        }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have tried making a function to be used with each button:

```
func performSegue(sender: UIButton) {
// checks if button's text matches the word tested variable's string
if sender.description == wordTested {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: "segueToAnswerCorrect", sender: AnyObject?)
    // I don't know how to pass data outside of prepareForSegue()
}
else {
self.performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: "segueToReviewCard", sender: AnyObject?)
    // pass data
}
}
```

I don't know how to properly work protocols and delegates yet and I'm not sure that that would be the solution or not.

If you have any information on this, this would be a life saver.

Comment: the second code block should actually work pretty well.

Comment: `prepareForSegue` is too late to control which segue is used.  You are on the right track with your `performSegue` function. The trick is that `sender` can be any object you like, so you can pass data that is then available in the `prepareForSegue` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually close. Just a minor change to your performSegue:

```
func performSegue(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.description == wordTested {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: "segueToAnswerCorrect", sender: sender)
    } else {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: "segueToReviewCard", sender: sender)
    }
}
```

You then connect all of the 4 buttons to this function.

Then you change the prepareForSegue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segueToAnsweredCorrect") {
        var acvc : AnsweredCorrectViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AnsweredCorrectViewController;
        acvc.testedWord = testedWord
        acvc.sentenceTransferred = randomSentenceToTransfer
    }
    if (segue.identifier == "segueToReviewCard") {
        var rcvc : ReviewCardViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ReviewCardViewController;
        rcvc.translationReviewed = testedTranslation
        rcvc.wordReviewed = testedWord            
    }
}
```

In the interface builder you need to setup the two segues, but no segues for the button action.

Comment: Create the two segues from the 1st view controller to the other two?

Comment: Yes, two segues from the controller with the four buttons to the two controllers you actually want to segue to. Giv the segues the correct identifiers and everything should work

Comment: the (sender: sender) is genius, I wrestled with that syntax for an hour at least.  However, the button.description isn't working.  How would I grab the text off a button, an IBAction in this case? Each button has both an outlet and an IBAction.  Do I need to make slightly different functions for each button?

Comment: ah, yes, have not even looked over that part :P do you want to read the text that is displayed? Then you would have to use something like `[sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal]`

Comment: @JeremyMize it would be recommended to store the word you are testing for and the correct button somewhere explicitly to remove the need for the strange tests for button titles.

Comment: After the function for randomly setting the text of all the buttons, I ran a println("\(ButtonAnswer1.titleForState(UIControlState.Normal)!)") and it printed the correct text.  however when I created the variable in the performSegue function var buttonText = sender.titleForState(UIControlState.Normal)! or buttonText = "\(sender.titleForState(UIControlState.Normal)!)" it both unwraps a nil value.  but the sender tag has the same . properties as the UIButtons.  confusing! haha

Comment: @JeremyMize hmmm, a somewhat cleaner way would be to assign all the wrong buttons a `tag` of 0, only the correct button gets a `tag` of 1, which you then can test for

Comment: Googled how to set `tag`s and it worked great! I changed the functions to change the outlet text as well as give it a tag.  Then on the IBActions from the buttons, instead of putting `performSegue(UIButton( ))` I changed it to `performSegue(ButtonAnswer1)` so I could extract the correct `tag`.  Thanks so much!